# Unable to resolve class HTTPBuilder inside gradler task

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, intellij-14

Why do some imports work for my regular groovy files inside the project

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 
'http-builder', version: '0.7.1'

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
```

When I try to use `HTTPBuilder` inside `build.gradle` is unable to resolve the class.

Am I missing a step for make them work inside a gradler task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the `http-builder` module classes available to the build script classpath, using the dedicated script block `buildscript`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    }
}
```

See:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:buildscript(groovy.lang.Closure)